# How to get Progress Bar to work with jQuery's AJAX Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to show a progress bar during AJAX file upload:

```
var data = new FormData();
    data.append('name', file.name); //something.jpg
    data.append('upload', blob); //data:image/jpeg;base64,/sd5a4de42qeasQW3123....

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/path/to/server/',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    xhr: function() {

        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
            // THIS IS ONLY RUNS ONCE!!!
            if(e.lengthComputable) {
                $('#progressbar').css('width', (e.loaded / e.total) * 100 + '%');
            }
        }, false);
        return xhr;

    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('.preview').addClass('uploading');
    },
    success: function(response) {
        if(response.success) {
            $('.preview')
                .removeClass('uploading')
                .addClass('uploaded');
        } else {
            // Fail
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        //
    }
});
```

The problem is the progress bar jumps straight to 100% instead of gradually going up 1%...24%...50...etc.

In the code above please look for this comment `// THIS IS ONLY RUNS ONCE!!!`. How can I get the `progress` event to fire properly?

Comment: if you want it to do using core JS please have a look on this.
http://www.binarytides.com/ajax-based-streaming-without-polling/

And for this your server script should capable to send output in intermediate stage.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/path/to/server/',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
            // THIS IS ONLY RUNS ONCE!!!
            if(e.lengthComputable) {
                $('#progressbar').css('width', (e.loaded / e.total) * 100 + '%');
            }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
        $('.preview').addClass('uploading');
    },
    success: function(response) {
        if(response.success) {
            $('.preview')
                .removeClass('uploading')
                .addClass('uploaded');
        } else {
            // Fail
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        //
    }
});
```